# Enabling Cors with Flask RestX

Tags: python, flask, flask-restx

Trying to add CORS to my flask app that is using an API created with flask-restx. Hopefully someone here can spot what I am doing wrong.

In the console that is running flask I don't get any relevant logs and the website is saying `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/test. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).`

Here is a reproduction of my user case that is giving me the same errors and is mimicking how I have set it up.

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_restx import Namespace, Resource, Api
from flask import jsonify, make_response
from flask import Blueprint, render_template_string
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
LOGGER = logging.getLogger("reprod-case")
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
LOGGER.info("Created LOGGER")
logging.getLogger('flask_cors').level = logging.DEBUG


# Create the restx namespace with a specified path
ns = Namespace(name='api_v1', path="/api/v1")


@ns.route('/test')
class Deck(Resource):
    def get(self):
        print("get")
        return make_response(jsonify({"message": "You did a Get!"}), 200)

    def put(self):
        print("Put")
        return None, 201


html_page = """
<html lang="en">
<body>
<button type="submit" name="myButton" value="Value">Click Me</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').on('click',function(e){
        const vote_value = e.currentTarget.attributes.value.value;
        console.log()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            crossDomain: true,
            withCredentials: true,
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/test',
            contentType: 'application/json'
        })
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
"""


# Blueprint for the webpage and add a route
bp = Blueprint("/", __name__)


@bp.route('/')
def home_route():
    return render_template_string(html_page)


# Setup the app, Cors, add the namespace and blueprint
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    # CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}},
    CORS(app,
         resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": ['http://192.168.50.16:5000', 'http://localhost:5000']}},
         supports_credentials=True
         )

    api = Api(doc="/api/", title="Endpoints")
    api.add_namespace(ns,  path="/api/v1")
    app.register_blueprint(bp)
    api.init_app(app)
    return app


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app_ = create_app()
    app_.run(debug=True)
```

I have also tried enabling cors by setting up an `after_request`

```py
    @app.after_request
    def enable_cors(response):
        response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "authorization,content-type")
        response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT")
        response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        return response
```

Comment: That _“CORS request did not succeed”_ message indicates the request is failing without the browser ever successfully connecting to the server — and so without getting any response at all from the server. So it’s actually completely unrelated to whatever CORS configuration you might have in place on that server. What happens when you try to open http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/test directly in your browser?